# Registering User using Flutter and PHP Laravel and saving User info with SharedPreferrence

Tags: flutter

I am trying to save result from json to SharedPreferrence but i keep getting  Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
This is my Code

```
 _register(BuildContext context, User user) async {
    var _userService = UserService();
    var registeredUser = await _userService.createUser(user);
    var encodeFirst = json.encode(registeredUser.body);
    var result = json.decode(encodeFirst);
    if(result['result'] == true){
      SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _prefs.setInt("userId", result["user"]["id"]);
      _prefs.setString("userName", result["user"]["name"]);
      _prefs.setString("userEmail", result["user"]["email"]);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CheckoutScreen(cartItems: this.widget.cartItems,)));
    } else {
      _showSnackMessage(Text('Failed to register the user!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),));
    }
  }
```

this is my User, UserService and Repository file

```
class User{
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String password;

  toJson(){
    return{
      'id': id.toString(),
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
  }
}

class UserService {
  Repository _repository;

  UserService(){
    _repository = Repository();
  }

  createUser(User user) async{
    return await _repository.httpPost('register', user.toJson());
  }
}

 httpPost(String api, data) async {
    return await http.post(_baseUrl + "/" + api, body: data);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you could check the runType of this result["user"]["id"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var encodeFirst = json.encode(registeredUser.body);` will call `User` `toJson()` 
And in `toJson()` , you have set `'id': id.toString(),` 
when you do `var result = json.decode(encodeFirst);` 
It's actually a `string` not `int`

Correct `toJson()` please see below

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final user = userFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    String email;
    String password;

    User({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.email,
        this.password,
    });

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        email: json["email"],
        password: json["password"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
    };
}
```